# Do I need Transit visa for Canada travelling from U.S

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, canada, eta

I want to know do I need a transit visa I am US F1 visa holder and having 2 hrs stop at Vancouver.

Comment: Where are you from (passport)?

Comment: @JuanCa I presume India from the tag

Comment: Apparently,they [need it](https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php?p1=in&fl=&s=yes).

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=IN&AR=00&DE=IN&TR=ca&user=GF&subuser=GFB2C), you need a visa to transit through Canada. You can apply for a free transit visa [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/apply.html). If you are travelling from or to the U.S., you don't even have to [give your biometrics](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/biometrics.asp) for the visa application.

Answer (score 0):

The only people eligible for transit without visa (if their passport normally needs a visa to visit Canada) are nationals of [Indonesia, Philippines, Thailand, Taiwan](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/without-visa/eligibility.html), and [China](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/without-visa/china-transit-eligibility.html). Since you are traveling on an Indian passport, you are not eligible for transit without visa, and since Indian nationals need a visa to visit Canada, you need a visa to transit Canada also. As Mophotla mentioned, it is free to apply for a Canadian transit visa.